# If $f$ is of Baire Class $1$, then $|f^{-1}[\{0\}]|=\mathfrak c$ or is countable.

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

A function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is of Baire Class $1$ if there exists a sequence $f_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ of continuous functions such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise.

I know that if $F\subset \mathbb R$ is closed, then $F$ is either countable or $|F|=|\mathbb R|=\mathfrak c$. Therefore, if $f$ is countinuous, then $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is either countable or has cardinality $\mathfrak c$. Is this also true if $f$ is of Baire Class 1?

Also, is it true that if $\mathbb R\setminus f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is uncountable, then it has cardinality $\mathfrak c$? (Supposing that $f$ is of Baire class $1$).

Edit: I noticed that these sets are $G_\delta$'s and $F_\sigma$'s.

Comment: If $f$ is the point-wise limit of a sequence of continuous functions then $f^{-1}\{x\}$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set for every $x$. We can show that an an uncountabls $G_{\delta}$ subset of  $\mathbb R$ has cardinal $c$.

Comment: An uncountable $F_{\sigma}$ subset of $\mathbb R$ also has cardinal $c.$

Comment: Hello @user254665. I know how to prove that an uncountable $F_\sigma$ space has cardinality $\mathfrak c$, and I know (but I have never seen a proof) that an uncountable $G_\delta$ has cardinality $\mathfrak c$. Do you know a direct proof (without talking about polish spaces)?

Comment: Not really.  A  non-empty completely metrizable space $S$ with no isolated points has a subspace  homeomorphic to the Cantor set, so  $|S|\geq c. $... A subspace  $Y$ of a complete metric space $X$  is completely metrizble iff  $Y$ is $G_{\delta}$ in $X$.... If $A$ is an uncountable $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\mathbb R$ then the subspace $$B=A \backslash  \cup \{(a,b):a,b\in \mathbb Q\land |(a,b)\cap A|\leq \aleph_0\} $$ is $G_{\delta},$ is not empty, and has no isolated points .